# Getting elif invalid syntax, tried finding solutions but nothing has worked so far

Tags: python

I'm currently doing a Microsoft course on Python for beginners. Usually when i struggle with errors in codes, I find my answers on this forum or elsewhere. However, with the following simple piece of code, I keep getting the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-16-f2834423fa1a>", line 7
    elif int(current_age) <= 20:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is what the task requires me to do:

> Create function age_20() that adds or subtracts 20 from your age for a
>   return value based on current age (use if)  call the funtion with user
>   input and then use the return value in a sentence  example age_20(25)
>   returns 5:
>
> "5 years old, 20 years difference from now"

And this is the piece of code I wrote:

```
    # [ ] complete age_20()

    def age_20():
        current_age = int(input("Enter your current age: "))
        if int(current_age) >= 20:
            return (int(current_age) - 20,("years old, 20 years difference from now")
        elif int(current_age) <= 20:
            return (int(current_age) + 20,("years old, 20 years in the future")

    (age_20())
```

It keeps giving me the error on the 'elif' line for some reason, and I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong. Help would be appreciated.

Also, I'm sorry if I didn't format the code correctly, I'm new to this forum so still learning. I am also aware this question has been asked before, but I have not found an answer that works for me yet.

Comment: check the retuns, it must be a bracket at the end of them.

Comment: you forgot to close the bracket in the statement `return (int(current_age) - 20,("years old, 20 years difference from now")`. Add another `)` in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things here. If you look at your return lines, you do not have matching parenthesis.

Also, current_age has already been cast to int.

Answer (score 0):

Add closing parentheses to the line before and to the line after.